# Merging one query into other as a sub-query and retriving multiple rows from it

Tags: sql

I have two different queries which is working fine, but what I want is to merge the second query into the first one, while doing so I get error as sub-query cannot return multiple values.

My first query is:

```
select distinct hm.hotel_name
from hotel_master hm , customer_bidding cb, bid b, hotel_admin ha
where cb.bid_id=b.bid_id 
  and b.ha_id=ha.ha_id
  and ha.hotel_id=hm.hotel_id
```

and My second query which i want to merge with first one is:

```
select distinct bid_id ,COUNT(bid_id) as bids from customer_bidding Group by bid_id order by bids desc
```

I would be thankful for any sort of help provided.

Results of queries :

[image]

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: what is ur desired result??? btw my 2 cents.. a subquery can have only one column in the SELECT clause, unless multiple columns are in the main query for the subquery to compare its selected columns. Subqueries that return more than one row can only be used with multiple value operators, such as the IN operator.

Answer (score 0):

just to be safe, since I don't know how your records looked like,

```
select  distinct hm.hotel_name, cb.bids
from    hotel_master hm, bid b, hotel_admin ha,
        (
            SELECT  bid_id,
                    COUNT(bid_id) as bids 
            from    customer_bidding 
            Group   by bid_id
        ) cb
where   cb.bid_id = b.bid_id and    
        b.ha_id = ha.ha_id and  
        ha.hotel_id = hm.hotel_id
```